# How to save the value of the string variable to an .xml file?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml

I can't write the value of a string variable using `XElement` to an .xml file.

I tried use `System.IO`:
`XDocument`, `XElement`

**code.cs:**

```
string variable ="sth";
XDocument xml_cip_c1 = new XDocument(
    new XComment("document"),
    new XElement("new root"),
    new XElement("name", variable)
);
```

**result.xml:**

```
<!--document-->
<new root>
    <name />
</new root>
```

Comment: are you looking for `<name value = "ABC" />`?

Comment: i dont how to edit post here
// variable
string variable ="sth";

Comment: click the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23779518) button below your post

Comment: @MichałParzych if one of the below answers fixed your issue, remember to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3):

Here you are Sir. Use `Value` property:

```
var yourVariable = "ABC";
XDocument xml_cip_c1 = new XDocument(
    new XComment("document"),
    new XElement("new_root",
    new XElement("name") { Value = yourVariable}));
```

This will produce the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--document-->
<new_root>
  <name>ABC</name>
</new_root>
```

But if you would like to add Attribute to your xml element, use the following code that uses `XAttribute`:

```
XDocument xml_cip_c1 = new XDocument(
    new XComment("document"),
    new XElement("new_root",
    new XElement("name", new XAttribute("name", yourVariable))));
```

Then you will get the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--document-->
<new_root>
  <name name="ASD" />
</new_root>
```

Answer (score 1):

**try this,**

**.cs Code**

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();  
settings.Indent =true;  
settings.IndentChars = ("    ");  
settings.CloseOutput = true;  
settings.OmitXmlDeclaration =true;                  
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("FileName.xml", settings))  
{  

    writer.WriteStartElement("newroot");  
    writer.WriteElementString("name", "ABC");  
    writer.WriteEndElement();  
    writer.Flush();  
}
```

**Result**
=> XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<newroot>
   <name>ABC</name>
</newroot>
```

Answer (score -1):

I use method from first post,

**code .cs:**

```
  private void sb_button_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
         variable1 = przycisk.Text;
         name_of_file_xml.Save(path_of_file);
        }

        static string variable1 ="sth";
```

I must use static var because it requires XAttribute from me.

I must use string with value, because if I declare string outwith value:

static string zmienna1 = null;

System.ArgumentNullException: 'The value cannot be zero.

**code .cs:**

```
Parameter name: value '
XDocument name_of_file_xml = new XDocument(
            new XComment("document"),
            new XElement("root",
                new XElement("name", new XAttribute ("name2", variable1 ))
                )
            );
```

In my project I would like to have a variable without value, is it possible?

because It don't assign the variable from button.text to me but the one set at the beginning